# What's the Applescript save function I can use to autosave a file in an open program every 5 minutes?

Tags: applescript, tableau-api, automator

I'm trying to create an ApplesScript function to automatically save a file every 5 minutes in a program called Tableau.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm stuck at what function to use for "Save"

```
tell application "Tableau" 
    if it is running then
        << This is where I want to check if the filename is generic, i.e. starts with "Book" >>
        << If it is generic, this is where I'd want to instruct it to prompt for Save As >>
        << If it is not generic, this is where I'd like to automatically Save the file in its current name and location >>
delay 300000
repeat
```

Comment: Automatic file saving is already implemented by Apple in the last 2 OS versions. There is nothing to do. if you need to reinvent that in older version of system, then you must write your script inside an "on idle" handler. your script will remain open for ever. at the end your must add "return xxx" where xxx is the number of seconds before next run. in your case 300 = 5 minutes